# Using function variables in another function

Tags: python

I'm struggling a bit as a new python learner, I have a "code" function that returns a concatenated code entered. I'm trying to create another function that takes that same code and prints the variables separately.

```
for exemple: n1 = 30, gender = m, n2 = 22
the code function returns : 30m22
and code_details function should print : 30m22, m, 30, 22

here's what i'm doing :

this one kinda works but not the code part

`def code():
    n1 = input("enter number 1 :")
    gender = input("enter male or female :")
    n2= input("enter number 2 :")

    return n1, gender, n2

def code_details():
    n1, gender, n2 = code()
    print(code, "\n", gender, "\n", n1, "\n", int(n2) + 5)

print(code_details())`

this one doesn't, and really most of my tries are like this.

`def code():
    n1 = input("enter number 1 :")
    gender = input("enter male or female :")
    n2= input("enter number 2 :")

    return n1 + gender + n2


def code_details(code):
    code_client() == code
    print(code, "\n", code.gender, "\n", code.n1, "\n", code.n2 + 5)

#print(code_details(code_client()))`
```

Comment: In your second attempt, the function `code()` already returns the concatenated string composed of the three user inputs. You can simply print the result, e.g. using `print(code())`, but you cannot *disentangle* the three components. The variables `n1`, `gender`, `n2` are internal *local* variables in the function, and are not visible outside it. And anyway, `code_client() == code` does not make much sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Love your name, and are you still playing basketball?

Try the code below,

```
def code():
    n1 = input("enter number 1 :")
    gender = input("enter male or female :")
    n2= input("enter number 2 :")
    result = "{n1}{gender}{n2}".format(n1=n1, gender=gender, n2=n2)
    return result, n1, gender, n2

def code_details():
    result, n1, gender, n2 = code()
    detailResult = "{result}, {n1}, {gender}, {n2}".format(result=result, n1=n1, gender=gender, n2=n2)
    print(detailResult)
```